# Error when trying to collect string ids (or simple string field) from collection of some objects

Tags: vb.net, linq, hashset

I have a class called `Order`. One of the field is `id`, which is just a unique identifier for an `Order` object.

So I do something simple to get those Order Ids

```
    Dim myOrderIds = (From x In Orders
                      Select x.id)
```

And I get that the class of `myOrderIds` is IEnumerable(Of String), which I expect. Now I want to check if myOrderIds contain the same thing with other OrderIds. So I should put both in a HashSet and use SetEqual right?

```
    Dim myOrderIdSet = myOrderIds.ToHashSet
```

That's like pretty obviously simple. Don't get simpler than this. I got an array, list, enumerable or whatever of ids, and I want to put it in a hashSet. Very simple

And I got this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30521 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ToHashSet' is most specific for these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function ToHashSet() As HashSet(Of String)' defined in 'Enumerable': Not most specific.
    Extension method 'Public Function ToHashSet() As HashSet(Of String)' defined in 'MoreEnumerable': Not most specific.    nicehash2   C:\Users\teguh\Dropbox\vb.net\gridtrading.vb    22  Active
```

It seems to me that the method ToHashSet is declared like twice somewhere and somehow they clash. But how can that be? The guy in Microsoft didn't code stuff up properly or what? And what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Microsoft's fault. The error message says that one of the options is from `MoreEnumerable`, which I think is from the `MoreLinq` NuGet package, which you must have installed. If you have imported both relevant namespaces then the compiler won't be able to tell which you intended to call. If you can't get rid of that NuGet package or one of the namespace imports in that context then you can't call the method as an extension. If you call it as a regular method then you can qualify the name to disambiguate it, e.g.

```vb
Dim myOrderIdSet = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToHashSet(myOrderIds)
```

The other alterntive would be to use the `HashSet(Of T)` constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable(Of T)` as an argument.

Comment: I suppose I can just uninstall morelinq. I think it's very sloppy of them to create a function that interfere with Micorosoft standard library.

Comment: Why would morelinq create a function that break microsoft function?

Comment: @obfuscated, I've never used MoreLinq or even heard of it before today. I can only guess at what their thinking was but maybe their intention is that you use all their methods instead of the standard methods. Like I said, if you remove one of the namespace imports then that particular call will work, so you could remove the `System.Linq` import and it will use the MoreLinq method without issue. I'm not sure whether that would break other standard LINQ calls though. MoreLinq would have had to redo them as well. If that were the case then you'd probably have seen this same issue before.

Comment: It seems that MoreLinq uses the toHashSet first and then Microsoft, not caring what lesser companies build, add that as .net features.

It seems that the new MoreLinq have removed that function. No more conflict. I think so.

Comment: @obfuscated, perhaps you're speaking tongue in cheek but it's not that Microsoft don't care. It's more like they can't keep track of every method that every third party library might provide and avoid adding useful functionality to the core framework so as not to clash with them.

Comment: Sort of. LOL. But it means the same thing. Not like they can't keep track. More like it doesn't make sense. Lesser companies should adapt to Microsoft and not the other way around I think. What does tongue in cheek mean?

I am pretty sure Microsoft Programmers know about the existence of another popular code that do what exactly they want to do. In fact, the name similarity may actually be a homage.